# Fixing scoring system

Tags: python

why won't this work 
Im new to python and just tried creating a math quiz and when i run this code i get syntax error
score is not defined

```
import random
print ("Welcome to Math Extreme PRE EARLY PRE-ALPHA")
def AskAQuestion1():
    global score
    Number1 = random.randint(0,10)
    Number2 = random.randint(0,10)
    print ("Calculate"+ str(Number1) + "+"+ str(Number2)+"")
    answer = input ()
    answer = int (answer)
    if answer == Number1+Number2:
         print ("Correct")
         score = score + 1
    else:
         print ("wrong")

print ("Pick A Level")
print ("1 = Level 1")
answer = input ()
answer = int (answer)
if answer == 1:
    print (" Ok the test will start")
    for repeat in range (100):
        AskAQuestion1()
    print ("Thank you for taking the test you scored",score,"% in the end")
```

Comment: There are many things wrong above. Could you show us the error as reported by the interpreter

Comment: The `SyntaxError`s **do** help, they tell you where the syntax is wrong (for example, as the code formatting clearly shows, you have an errant quote mark `"`). First fix the syntax, then you can move on to testing the logic.

Comment: @ProRyan what does *"problem"* mean? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)? **Edit the question** to describe precisely what the issue is.

Comment: @jonsharpe I'm asking what the problem is so that i can fix it.

Comment: Yes, and you have to **clearly describe why you think there's a problem**. You mention a syntax error, so **provide the full traceback**. Don't just say *"problem"*, actually describe what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `score = 0` otherwise it won't know what to add in the above line at line 3
it will look like:

```
import random                                                               
print ("Welcome to Math Extreme PRE EARLY PRE-ALPHA")                       
score = 0                                                                   
def AskAQuestion1():                                                        
    global score                                                            
    Number1 = random.randint(0,10)                                          
    Number2 = random.randint(0,10)                                          
    print ("Calculate"+ str(Number1) + "+"+ str(Number2)+"")                
    answer = input ()                                                       
    answer = int (answer)                                                   
    if answer == Number1+Number2:                                           
         print ("Correct")                                                  
         score = score + 1                                                  
    else:                                                                   
         print ("wrong")
```

Comment: I tried it and it still isn't working

Comment: keep global score where it is and just add score = 0 in line 3

Answer (score 0):

You messed up opening and closing your quotes in the line:

`print ("Calculate"+ str(Number1) + "+"+ str("Number2)+"")`

It should be:

```
    print ("Calculate"+ str(Number1) + "+"+ str(Number2)+"")
```

this has altered use of quotes throughout the code. That's just one clearly visible error. First you need to correct that and then check for rest.

Comment: thanks i messed that up when copying the code onto the website the problem I'm having is with the scoring system

Comment: When you don't need to have inline code, I'd recommend you to put one line before the code and indent the code using 4 spaces - this way the code gets syntax highlightning.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I think that you wanted to comment the question, not the answer...